# When trying to INSERT NULL in a foreign key I get the error Could not insert: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, insert, null, foreign-keys

I have a table `tbl_weine` with a column `qualitaetsID`. There is a foreign key restriction on the column `qualitaetsID` in the table `ktbl_qualitaet`. The values there are 1,2,3,4,5

now I want to enter one new line into the table `tbl_weine` with `qualitaetsID` = NULL.

Surprisingly I get a  "Could not insert: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". I always thought that NULL values are not affected by foreign constraints.

Okay: Erst die tbl_weine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_weine` (
`WeinID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `WeingutID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Marke` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Jahrgang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FarbID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Lage` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `QualitaetsID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QualitaetsregionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuesseID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Kommentar` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trinkoptimum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MHD` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ausverkauft` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1446 ;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_weine`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`WeinID`), ADD KEY `FK_WEINE_WEINGUTid` (`WeingutID`), ADD KEY `FK_WEINE_FARBid` (`FarbID`), ADD KEY `FK_WEINE_QUALITAETSid` (`QualitaetsID`), ADD KEY `FK_WEINE_QUALITAETSREGIONid` (`QualitaetsregionID`), ADD KEY `FK_WEINE_SUESSEid` (`SuesseID`);

MODIFY `WeinID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1446;

--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_weine`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_WEINE_WEINGUTid` FOREIGN KEY (`WeingutID`) REFERENCES `ktbl_weingut` (`WeingutID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_weine_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FarbID`) REFERENCES `ktbl_farbe` (`FarbID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_weine_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`QualitaetsID`) REFERENCES `ktbl_qualitaet` (`QualitaetsID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_weine_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`QualitaetsregionID`) REFERENCES `ktbl_qualitaetsregion` (`QualitaetsregionID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_weine_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`SuesseID`) REFERENCES `ktbl_suesse` (`SuesseID`);

Dann die ktbl_qualitaet:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ktbl_qualitaet` (
  `QualitaetsID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Qualitaet` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LandID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `ktbl_qualitaet`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`QualitaetsID`), ADD KEY `FK_KTBL_QUALITAET_LANDid` (`LandID`);

ALTER TABLE `ktbl_qualitaet`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ktbl_qualitaet_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LandID`) REFERENCES `ktbl_land` (`LandID`);
```

My FORM:

```
<html>
<body>
Weinerfassung <br><br>

<form name="erfassen" action="process.php" method="post">
<p> Marke <input type="text" name="marke"/></p>
<p> Name <input type="text" size="40" name="name"/>*</p>
<p> Jahrgang <input type="number" name="jahrgang" value="<?php $date = date('Y')-1 ; echo $date;?>"/>*</p>
<p> Lage <input type="text" size="80" name="lage"/></p>

<?php
/* Globale Variablen unnd Funktionen laden */
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

/* Am Host anmelden */
$accounts = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) 
or die (mysql_error()) ;

/* Datenbank auswählen */
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $accounts) ;

/* Codes erzeugen */
$sql_weingut = "
SELECT WeingutID, Weingut, Region, Land
FROM ktbl_weingut as w
LEFT JOIN ktbl_region as r
ON w.regionenID = r.regionenID
LEFT JOIN ktbl_land as l
ON r.landid = l.landID
ORDER BY Weingut, Land
" ;

$sql_farbe = "
SELECT *
FROM ktbl_farbe
" ;

$sql_suesse = "
SELECT *
FROM ktbl_suesse
" ;

$sql_qualitaet = "
SELECT *
FROM ktbl_qualitaet
" ;

$sql_qualitaetsregion = "
SELECT QualitaetsregionID, Qualitaetsstufe, Region
FROM ktbl_qualitaetsregion as q
left join ktbl_region as r
on q.regionenid=r.regionenid
" ;

$sql_rebsorte = "
SELECT *
FROM ktbl_rebsorte
where isnull(Rebsorte) = FALSE
order by Rebsorte
" ;


/* Ergebnisse abspeichern */
$result_weingut             = mysql_query($sql_weingut,             $accounts) or die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());
$result_farbe               = mysql_query($sql_farbe,               $accounts) or die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());
$result_suesse              = mysql_query($sql_suesse,              $accounts) or die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());
$result_qualitaet           = mysql_query($sql_qualitaet,           $accounts) or die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());
$result_qualitaetsregion    = mysql_query($sql_qualitaetsregion,    $accounts) or die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());
$result_rebsorte            = mysql_query($sql_rebsorte,            $accounts) or die('Could not query: ' . mysql_error());


 /* Ergebnisse ausgeben */
 echo  "<p> Weingut <select name='weingutID'>";
      echo "<option value=0> - ausw&auml;hlen - </option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_weingut))
{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['WeingutID'] . "'>" . $row['Weingut'] . " aus " . $row['Region'] . ", " . $row['Land'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>*<p>";


echo  "<p> Farbe <select name='farbID'>";
      echo "<option value=0> - ausw&auml;hlen - </option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_farbe))
{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['FarbID'] . "'>" . $row['Farbe'] . "</option>";
}
    echo "</select>*<p>";


echo  "<p> S&uuml;&szlig;e <select name='suesseID'>";
      echo "<option value=0> - ausw&auml;hlen - </option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_suesse))
{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['SuesseID'] . "'>" . $row['Suesse'] . "</option>";
}
    echo "</select><p>";


echo  "<p> Qualit&auml;t <select name='qualitaetsID'>";
      echo "<option value=0> - ausw&auml;hlen - </option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_qualitaet))
{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['QualitaetsID'] . "'>" . $row['Qualitaet'] . "</option>";
}
    echo "</select><p>";


echo  "<p> Qualit&auml;tsregion <select name='qualitaetsregionID'>";
      echo "<option value=0> - ausw&auml;hlen - </option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_qualitaetsregion))
{
      echo "<option value='" . $row['QualitaetsregionID'] . "'>" . $row['Qualitaetsstufe'] . ' ' . $row['Region'] . "</option>";
}
    echo "</select><p>";

?>

<p> Kommentar <input type="text" size="100" name="kommentar"/></p>
<p> <input type="submit" value="Wein erfassen"/></p>
</form>

<?php
/*
<form name="anz_rebsorten" action="erfassen.php" method="post">
<p> Anzahl Rebsorten <input type="number" name="anz_rebsorten"/></p>
<p> <input type="submit" value="Anzahl bestaetigen"/></p>
</form>
*/
?>


<form name="rebsorten" action="erfassen.php" method="post">
<?php
$anz_rebsorten = 1; // $_POST['anz_rebsorten'];
$i = 1;

while ($i <= $anz_rebsorten)
{
    echo  '<p> Rebsorte ' . $i. '<select name="rebsorte' . $i .'">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_rebsorte))
    {
        if ($row['weitere Namen'] == NULL)
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['RebsortenID'] . "'>" . $row['Rebsorte'] . "</option>";
        }
        else echo "<option value='" . $row['RebsortenID'] . "'>" . $row['Rebsorte'] . " (" . $row['weitere Namen'] . ")</option>";

    }
    echo "</select><p>";
    $i++;
}

?>

<p> <input type="submit" value="Rebsorte(n) erfassen"/></p>
</form>



</body> 
</html>
```

MY INPUT Process:

```
<?php
/* Globale Variablen unnd Funktionen laden */
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

/* Am Host anmelden */
$accounts = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) 
or die (mysql_error()) ;

/* Datenbank auswählen */
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $accounts) ;

if (
    /* Pflichtfelder prüfen */
    !empty($_POST['name']) == TRUE AND 
    !empty($_POST['jahrgang']) == TRUE AND 
    isset($_POST['weingutID']) == TRUE AND !$_POST['weingutID'] == 0 AND
    isset($_POST['farbID']) == TRUE AND !$_POST['farbID'] == 0
    )
    {
    /* Eingabedaten der Pflichtfelder abspeichern */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $jahrgang = $_POST['jahrgang'];
    $weingutID = $_POST['weingutID'];
    $farbID = $_POST['farbID'];

    /* optionale Felder prüfen und Eingabedaten speichern bzw. Defaults abspeichern */
    if  (
        isset($_POST['marke']) == TRUE
        )
        {
        $marke = $_POST['marke'];
        }
        else $marke = NULL;

    if  (
        isset($_POST['lage']) == TRUE
        )
        {
        $lage = $_POST['lage'];
        }
        else $lage = NULL;

    if  (
        isset($_POST['kommentar']) == TRUE
        )
        {
        $kommentar = $_POST['kommentar'];
        }
        else $kommentar = NULL;

    echo 'Der Wert der Variablen qualitaetsID ist ' . $_POST['qualitaetsID'] . '<br>';
    if  (
        isset($_POST['qualitaetsID']) == TRUE AND !$_POST['qualitaetsID'] == 0 
        )
        {
        Echo 'Branch 1';
        $qualitaetsID = $_POST['qualitaetsID'];
        }
        else 
        {
        Echo 'Branch 2 <br>';
        $qualitaetsID = NULL;
        Echo 'Ist Wert der variablen qualitaetsID Null? ' . is_null($qualitaetsID);
        }

    if  (
        isset($_POST['qualitaetsregionID']) == TRUE AND !$_POST['qualitaetsregionID'] == 0
        )
        {
        $qualitaetsregionID = $_POST['qualitaetsregionID'];
        }
        else $qualitaetsregionID = NULL;        

    if  (
        isset($_POST['suesseID']) == TRUE AND !$_POST['suesseID'] == 0
        )
        {
        $suesseID = $_POST['suesseID'];
        }
        else $suesseID = 1;

    if  (
        isset($_POST['ausverkauft']) == TRUE
        )
        {
        $ausverkauft = $_POST['ausverkauft'];
        }
        else $ausverkauft = 0;

    /* Code erzeugen */
    $sqlin = "
        INSERT INTO tbl_weine (WeingutID, Marke, Name, Jahrgang, FarbID, Lage, QualitaetsID, QualitaetsregionID, SuesseID, Kommentar)
        VALUES ('$weingutID', '$marke', '$name', '$jahrgang', '$farbID', '$lage', '$qualitaetsID', '$qualitaetsregionID', '$suesseID', '$kommentar')
        " ;

    /* Daten einlesen */
    mysql_query($sqlin, $accounts) or die('Could not insert: ' . mysql_error());

    }
    else echo 'Bitte fuellen Sie alle Pflichtfelder aus!'


?>
```

I found out the solution myself: the Variable containing the value NULL is in ''! I just had to remove the ''. It works now!

Comment: Please show us the full `create table` statements and the `insert` you are you using. You also have to specify which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: What is your real question? The error message seems pretty clear to me. If you tell us why you do not want to insert a row with a proper FK value, we could perhaps give a better answer.

Comment: Well the error is not clear to me at all. The column is not mandatory. I have never had problems with that issue before on Mysql... but now I am entering data through a php web form and there is the error. I want to know how I can allow null inserts and keep the foreign key constraint :-)